# Java Spring controller breakpoint and JUnit

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have a Spring REST application with Junit tests. I run the app in Eclipse and I start the tests. If I set breakpoints in the Junit class it works fine and it stops execution but if I set breakpoints directly in the called controller nothing happen.
What I am doing wrong?

```
@Test
public void testAddVideoData() throws Exception {
    Video received = videoSvc.addVideo(video);
    VideoStatus status = videoSvc.setVideoData(received.getId(),
            new TypedFile(received.getContentType(), testVideoData));
    assertEquals(VideoState.READY, status.getState());

    Response response = videoSvc.getData(received.getId());
    assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());

    InputStream videoData = response.getBody().in();
    byte[] originalFile = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(testVideoData));
    byte[] retrievedFile = IOUtils.toByteArray(videoData);
    assertTrue(Arrays.equals(originalFile, retrievedFile));
}
```

and this is the method I want to set the breakpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/video/{id}/data" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody VideoStatus addVideoData(AtomicLong id, @RequestParam("data")
MultipartFile videoData) {

    VideoStatus videoStatus= new VideoStatus(VideoState.PROCESSING);


    try {
        videoDataMgr = VideoFileManager.get();
        Video video = videos.get(id);

        if(!videoDataMgr.hasVideoData(video)) {
            InputStream in = videoData.getInputStream();
            videoDataMgr.saveVideoData(video, in);
        }
        videoStatus.setState(VideoState.READY);


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // SAVE IT TO DISK

    return videoStatus;

}
```

Comment: Can you post your Junit test along with the mocking you did.

Comment: If you run the app, then start the tests, then the app runs in a separate JVM from the  tests. So using debug mode when running the tests will allow debugging the tests, running in the tests JVM, but not the controller, running in a separate JVM. You need to start the app in debug mode, too. Of course, all of these are conjectures, because we have no idea of what the tests look like.

Comment: Added Junit test in the post. I have tried running the app in debug mode too but it stops execution somewhere else at the beginning

Comment: @JBNizet your solution actually works. Thanks. You can write an official response and i will accept it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since application and tests run in 2 different JVM, you have to (using Eclipse):

- for tests: "runs as Java Application"
- for the application: "debug as Java Application", setting breakpoints whenever you need.